# I want Android to remember my currently playing song and playlist

Tags: music-player

I am currently using the stock `Music Player` for my phone.  Whenever I pause a song, leave the app, and go back to the app, it *sometimes* goes back to my "All" songs view, not remembering what I was currently playing.  It appears that this behavior depends on whether or not the App was closed.  For instance, if the app closes by my actions via the Task Manager, or it closes on its own based on memory/CPU management, it loses track of what it is doing.

Is there a setting, or another music app, that allows me to play songs and have that song and playlist remembered even if the app is closed?

I'm running FroYo (2.2) on a Samsung Captivate (Galaxy S series).

Comment: Please let us know which device you have - since different phones may have different music players.

Comment: Try holding the Home key, switching to another app from the list of apps that pops up and doing whatever, and then going back.  Does it keep its state in that case?

Comment: @Matthew, I'll add an additional detail I found out.

Comment: @Matthew, but to answer your question, yes, it does keep its state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Android version of Winamp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp) seems to do a fairly decent job of this.  I barely use it (this particular aspect isn't that important to me), but I've just fired it up after about a week, and it picked up exactly where it left off.

Comment: I downloaded this a few days ago.  It brings flashbacks of 1998.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to increase how long apps stay in memory.  It's pretty simple to do this on a Galaxy S -- install [One Click Lag Fix](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rc.QuickFixLagFixR2D) from the Market, open it, go to **Alter minfree** and change it to **Moderate** (check **Set On Boot** too).  I use this setting and apps usually only get killed if I play Angry Birds for a while and the phone needs to kill them to free up memory.

Comment: Matthew, I'm interested in this app, but the link seems to be expired and a search didn't bring it up in the market. Does it have a new name?

Comment: @Chance Looks like they changed the package name from `com.rc.QuickFixLagFixR2` to `com.rc.QuickFixLagFixR2D`, I've updated the link.